# Get id of element

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get the id of the active tab. My code is not working. Help

```js
//if it's the second tab, refresh it
var liID = $('#menu').hasClass('active').attr(id);
console.log(liID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#container" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Container">
      <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                            </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#parameters" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Parameters">
      <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#results" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Results">
      <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you read the console? The error message is clear as day.

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting the li that is active and you are missing quotes. You are chekcing to see if the "menu" element is active and you read its value.

```
$('#menu').find('.active').attr('id')
```

or

```
$('#menu .active').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be in quotes, otherwise it's thought of as a variable, which you don't have declared.

Next, your attempt to get the ID is incorrect because **[`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** returns a boolean, not the element that has the class, so calling `.attr()` on the return value will fail.

Lastly, your `active` element doesn't even have and `id` anyway.

Here's a corrected version:

```js
//if it's the second tab, refresh it
if($('#menu li').hasClass('active')){
  var liID = $('#menu li.active').attr("id");
  console.log(liID);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu">
  <li role="presentation" class="active" id="HELLO">
    <a href="#container" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Container">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#parameters" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Parameters">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#results" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Results">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But really, this should be even simpler:

```js
// Just query for the active element and then use it:
console.log($('#menu li.active').attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu">
  <li role="presentation" class="active" id="HELLO">
    <a href="#container" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Container">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#parameters" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Parameters">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
    <a href="#results" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Results">
      <span class="round-tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap id with quote. hasClass returns a boolean. So

```
var liID = $('#menu li.active').attr('id');
```

will set liID to id of an li element with a parent "menu" and with class active, if any.